# Java XStream -Serializing Date objects results in the time being incorrect by an hour

Tags: java, xml, serialization, date

I am using XStream to serialize an object which contains a Date field to XML and back again. However, the dates written to XML are an hour earlier than the actual dates I created.

```
MyComplexObject o = new MyComplexObject();
o.addChild(new MyComplexObjectChild(2, {0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5}, new Date(1111111111));
System.out.println(new Date(1111111111)); //Tue Jan 13 21:38:31 GMT 1970
//serialize using XStream
```

This is the outputted XML:

```
 <MyComplexObject>           
     <children>
         <MyComplexObjectChild>
              <someNumber>2</someNumber>
              <someOtherNumbers>
                  <double>0.1</double>
                  <double>0.1</double>
                  <double>0.2</double>
                  <double>0.3</double>
                  <double>0.5</double>
              </someOtherNumbers>
              <date>1970-01-13 21:38:31.111 GMT</date>
        </MyComplexObjectChild>
    </children>
</MyComplexObject>
```

Now, deserialize using XStream:

```
MyComplexObject o = xstream.fromXML(output);
System.out.println(o.getDate()) //Tue Jan 13 22:38:31 GMT 1970
```

As you can see the outputted date is an hour out - how can I fix this?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: If the XStream serialization and `System.out.println` are happening on different machines, check their timezone settings.

Comment: They're happening on the same machine...

Comment: Ah ok, I rechecked. The date in the deserialized object is incorrect. Will change question to show that.

Comment: Don't use the `toString()` from java.util.Date... print out the results of calling `getTime()` on it. That's the internal data representation, with no messing around for time zones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect there's something strange going on in your JRE:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Date d = new Date(1111111111);
      System.out.println(d); // Prints Tue Jan 13 21:38:31 GMT 1970
  }
}
```

So the XML looks correct to me.

Testing with C# just to check...

EDIT: Just to confuse things even more, .NET and Mono seem to think it's 20:38:31:using System;

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTimeOffset epoch = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                                                  TimeSpan.Zero);
        TimeSpan millis = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1111111111);
        // Prints 1970-01-13 20:38:31Z
        Console.WriteLine((epoch + millis).ToString("u"));
    }
}
```

I'm confused...

EDIT: Okay, we can work this out pretty easily. 1111111111 milliseconds is ~308.64 hours, which is 12 days and 20 hours... which means .NET is right here.

I have *no idea* why Java claims it's 9pm. Trying with Joda...

EDIT: Joda confirms the .NET result:

```
import org.joda.time.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      DateTime dt = new DateTime(1111111111, DateTimeZone.UTC);
      System.out.println(dt); // Prints 1970-01-13T20:38:31.111Z
  }
}
```

So that leaves two questions:

- Why is the OP's machine printing 22:38:31?
- Why is my machine printing 21:38:31?

EDIT: Okay, making progress:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Date date = new Date(1111111111);
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
      df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      // Prints 1970-01-13 20:38:31 UTC
      System.out.println(df.format(date));
  }
}
```

I *wonder* whether GMT wasn't UTC in 1970, which would explain things... checking now...

EDIT: Okay, I've got some idea of what's causing confusion here. From 27 October 1968 to 31 October 1971, Britain was in UTC+1 (effectively - UTC itself wasn't introduced until 1972). So when it's saying "GMT" here it *really* means "the time zone of Europe/London at this time" which wasn't really GMT. It's particularly unfortunate that this weirdness happened aroud the Unix epoch...

Comment: Prints Tue Jan 13 21:38:31 GMT 1970 for me too!